# Using the akavel rsrc tool

Tags: go, manifest, rsrc

Basically I am following this tutorial:
https://gowalker.org/github.com/lxn/walk

But when it comes to building the manifest file into a .syso file using the akavel rsrc tool I am running into the following error:

```
rsrc : The term 'rsrc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have run the go get and the package is in the goprojects folder and I am only changing the make of the manifest from 'test.manifest' to windowService.manifest' but this is updated in the command and I don't think this is my error?

IF you could shed any light on this I would be grateful as google doesn't seem to return anything helpful to this tool specifically!

Comment: It just looks like `rsrc` isn't in your PATH

Comment: thanks this was the error!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/75905019/3126973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same error you need to actually run the rsrc, so for me the steps were:

1) Navigate in command line to the location of rsrc.exe:

*For me it was 'C:\GoProjects\bin'*

2) Run the command:

```
.\rsrc.exe -manifest '*PATHTOMANIFESTLOCATION*' -o rsrc.syso
```

3) Copy the rsrc.syso file back to the location of my goproject before running go build.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do what @JackFrost mentioned is to use your %GOPATH% environment variable.

This saved me a small headache from compiling my manifest file in the bin file.

`%GOPATH%\bin\rsrc.exe -manifest file.manifest -o rsrc.syso`

Answer (score 1):

Executable are no longer installed via `go get` but through `go install`. For this particular case

```bash
go install -v github.com/akavel/rsrc@latest
```

does the needful.