# How to install rsrc.exe on Windows

Tags: windows, go, rsrc

I'm trying to set up a GUI for my golang app, using this:

https://github.com/lxn/walk

but I'm stuck on the step to compile the manifest:

```
go get github.com/akavel/rsrc
rsrc -manifest test.manifest -o rsrc.syso
```

On the second command, I get this error:

```
bash: rsrc: command not found
```

This is totally understandable - I don't have such command installed on my OS, but the problem is, I don't know how to install it. Google/bing search is totally useless in this case, since it just directs me to the rsrc tool github page:

[rsrc tool](https://github.com/akavel/rsrc)

And that page states, that installation command is "go get github.com/akavel/rsrc", but it makes no sense to me - "go get" only gets a package for my project, it is not meant to install anything on my OS. Am I missing something?

Likely, I'm just going to use another framework, but I'm really curious, why doesn't this one work.

Comment: Executable are no longer installed via go get but through go install. Try `go install -v github.com/akavel/rsrc@latest`. (The documentation _was_ accurate several years ago; it no longer is.)

Comment: That was it, thanks! I'm not from the era when "go get" would install stuff, so I didn't know that was some obsolete function. Also, looks like the documentation is not the only obsolete about this package. Anyway, this answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments, go get command used to install things a few years back, but it no longer does.

To install rsrc, do:

```
go install -v github.com/akavel/rsrc@latest
```